# Semantic HTML - Navigation in Sidebar

Tags: html, navigation, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a sidebar which contains the main navigation for the app. It also contains a `button` which triggers the open/close of the sidebar. In terms of semantics, how should the markup look like?

- Should i wrap the sidebar in aside and then have a nav around only
  the main navigation, excluding the open/close trigger.
- Or wrap the whole sidebar in a `nav` including the open/close trigger
- Or wrap the sidebar in a `section`, which contains a `nav` excluding the
  open/close trigger?
- Or not have any `section` or `aside`, but only have a `nav` excluding the trigger, in which case am I still following the below best practice. Should the trigger be treated as content? or something that should be part of the outline of the web page?

The [W3][1] suggests:

> It is a best practice to include ALL content on the page in landmarks,
>   so that screen reader users who rely on them to navigate from section
>   to section do not lose track of content.

The current structure resembles this:

sidebar

- main nav

  - nav item 1
  - nav item 2
- trigger to open/close the sidebar

Answer (score 3):

The `<aside>` element is used for tangentially related content to main content of the page and are often represented visually as sidebars. Using it for navigation would not be completely confusing to a screen-reader, but you must, in this case, add a `role` of either `complementary` or `region` to it.

I would expect this `<aside>` to group at least several different `<nav>` elements, so for your use-case of having a single menu, I would definitely just go with having the sidebar menu area be a `<nav>`. Remember to give it a nice `aria-label` by the way. Something like `aria-label=“Primary”` will suffice for your primary navigation.

Consider hiding the toggle button for screen-readers with `aria-hidden=“true”`, if toggling does not do them any good. In that case the `<nav>` must never be hidden with `display: none` as it would render it invisible and un-toggleable to screen-readers.

```
<nav aria-label="Primary”>
 <button aria-hidden="true">Toggle menu</button>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: `Consider hiding the toggle button for screen-readers with aria-hidden=“true”, if toggling does not do them any good.`  Ack!  Please don't do that!  The toggle should work for **everyone** and absolutely should set CSS `display:none` on the menu.  If a sighted user wants to collapse the menu to help reduce visual clutter, the screen reader **also** should be able to collapse the menu to reduce audible clutter.

Comment: I generally agree. I’ve seen solutions, where the toggle’s only purpose was to provide more screen-space for viewing the underlying content, and the menu was purposely left always ‘visible’ for screen-readers to easily navigate to it as a landmark. In that case the toggle button changed nothing for a screen-reader user. For the solution proposed above (and most other solutions) I would also personally prefer to keep the option of toggling on/off.

Comment: having it always "visible" for SR users makes it harder for SR users to navigate past the thing that was hidden.